# how can I do conditional insert in postgres when there can be concurrent inserts that can create conflict?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, transactions, sql-insert, distributed-transactions

I am trying to write an experimentation framework where user can schedule some experiments based on **location-ids** and **time**.

my table schema looks like :

```
TABLE experiment (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    locationIds varchar[] NOT NULL,
    timeStart timestamp NOT NULL,
    timeEnd timestamp NOT NULL,
    createdAt timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updatedAt timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

there are insert operations to be done with condition that the location(s) and time should not overlap.
I wanted to know what can be done to avoid in-consistency of data state when there are 2 concurrent inserts taken up where location OR time overlaps,

Ideally I want one of the insert to succeed, but I am fine If both fails and application is supposed to retry again.

Few Approached I tried to think:

Approach:

**APPROACH-1**

1. Have an **enable** column that tells whether certain entry is valid
   OR not.
2. I insert the experiment schedule entry with **enable=FALSE**
3. Then I check if there is any other entry which is enabled and is
   overlapping with the current Insert.
4. **IF** there is such entry then I do nothing and that experiment is not
   scheduled. **Else** I update the entry to **enable=TRUE**.

Problem : If there is a concurrent conflicting insert, then both will get **enable=TRUE** when both cleared the step-3.

I gave a thought if I let the transaction-isolation level to be read-uncommitted then also, I can't differentiate the ones in process and the ones already **enable=TRUE**

Then I thought, If I mark enable as a enum [IN_PROGRESS, ENABLED, DISABLED] then approach will look like this.

**APPROACH-2**

1. Have an **enable** column that tells whether certain entry is [IN_PROGRESS, ENABLED, DISABLED]
2. I insert the experiment schedule entry with **enable=IN_PROGRESS**
3. Then I check if there is any other entry which is **enable=ENABLED** OR **enable=IN_PROGRESS** and is overlapping with the current Insert.
4. **IF** there is such entry then I update **enable=DISABLED** and that experiment is not
   scheduled. **Else** I update the entry to **enable=ENABLED**.

Problem : If there is a concurrent conflicting insert, then both will get **enable=DISABLED** when both cleared the step-3 and get such overlapping entry.

If the transaction-isolation level is **READ-COMMITTED** then this will only work IF each step is a transaction, rather whole process as one transaction.
If the transaction-isolation level is **READ-UNCOMMITTED** then this can be taken up as one transaction, with DISABLED state can be taken as a ROLLBACK step too.

**APPROACH-3**

Using Trigger Based solution as I am using POSTGRES, I can add a trigger for each insert operation, post insert where I check for such overlapping entry, if there is none, then I update the row to have **enable=TRUE**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enable_if_unique() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    UPDATE experiment
    SET NEW.enable=true
    WHERE (SELECT count(1)
           FROM experiment
           WHERE enable= true AND location_Ids && OLD.location_ids AND (OLD.timeStart, OLD.timeEnd) OVERLAPS (timeStart, timeEnd)
        ) = 0;
    RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER enable_if_unique_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON experiment FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE enable_if_unique();
```

I am not sure about Approach 3 because I feel it require trigger to act in a serial manner for each insert operation so that one of the Experiment is actually enabled while rest of overlapping ones are disabled.

**APPROACH-4**

From online search for other possible solution, I See Inserts taken up using Select Statement and the WHERE clause helping to add the required condition.

```
INSERT INTO experiment(id, name, locationIds, timeStart, timeEnd) 
SELECT 1, 'exp-1', ARRAY[123,234,345], '2020-03-13 12:00:00' 
WHERE (
       SELECT count(1) 
       FROM EXPERIMENT 
       WHERE enable= true 
             AND 
             location_Ids && OLD.location_ids 
             AND 
             (OLD.timeStart, OLD.timeEnd) OVERLAPS (timeStart, timeEnd)
      ) = 0;
```

I feel there is still possibility of consistency issue as both concurrent operations will not be able to read each in the SELECT statement checking the constraint.

**Final APPROACH : APPROACH-2**

I like to know following things :

1. Which is the best approach in terms of scalability and high-throughput ?
2. Which approach is actually making the sure the data consistency is maintained?
3. Any Other Approach that I could have used and missed here!!!

***Newbie To POSTGRES, Will APPRECIATE example OR links***

Comment: If the location IDs were integers, you could use an exclusion constraint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am looking for a generic approach, but for argument sake, I can try to create an integer id from the varchar one, Can you provide some example here.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2e181268d6de9b66d717cc7b9f949eb

Comment: "*If the transaction-isolation level is READ-UNCOMMITTED*" - Postgres does not support read-uncommitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name

we can use exclusion constraint :

```
-- this prevents overlaps in the locationids AND the time range
alter table experiment 
  add constraint no_overlap 
  exclude using gist (locationids with &&, tsrange(timestart, timeend) with &&);
```